# CSS files are not deferring in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello I am trying to deferring following CSS using  `<params>defer="defer"</params>` tag but it is not working. Here is my style sheet which I want to defer:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/infortis/ultra-megamenu/ultra-megamenu.css</name><params>defer="defer"</params></action>
```

The tool which I am using to check is: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=

So please let me know the correct way to defer the CSS. However my JS are successfully deferring and asyncing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Defer is a **boolean attribute** which  must be used only for external scripts provided if `src` attribute is present

```
<script src="name.js" defer></script>
```

I don't think so you can defer CSS using `defer` attribute.

Try using `rel="preload"`

```
  <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
```

Comment: So how it could be achieved in magento 1.9?

Comment: try rel="preload" check in all browsers which fastens up loading time of css